# Add an App to every "Open With" Menu?

Tags: macos, text-editor

Is there any way I can make it so one specific app always shows up in the "Open With" menu, in addition to all of the default options?

I want to be able to right-click on a file, and in addition to seeing all of the normal apps that open it, I also want to be able to choose something like BBEdit, so I can also view the raw code.

Maybe the approach should be reversed, is there a way I can tell the system that BBEdit is a valid app to open *every* file type?

This would be a very handy, time-saving mod.

Comment: BBEdit should already have listed itself for every file type *it is capable of opening*. What would be the point of adding photos, video, audio or disk images etc, or any binary file?

Comment: Data recovery apps often mis-categorize what it thinks various files are. It would be nice to be able to quickly open them in BBEdit, view the content, and be sure their content matches their extension.

Comment: OK... that would appear to be an odd way of thinking. Pre-emptive disaster recovery, rather than just having a good backup strategy in the first place...

Comment: It's actually not odd at all - you have misunderstood the request. If you work with data recovery apps, and have the _results_ on your Mac - you want to be able to inspect the recovered files quickly. It is not to do with disaster recovery of the Mac itself, and thus have nothing to do with backup strategy. The files you do data recovery on might not be your own, but rather data recovery done for friends, family or even clients.

Comment: @jksoegaard exactly.

Comment: "BBEdit should already have listed itself for every file type it is capable of opening" is not accurate. There are many filetypes that are XML based, that BBEdit doesn't make itself an app for. For example, .webloc safari 'bookmark' files and .svg vector images. Having BBEdit 'always' be in the list would be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

The following Ask Different answer may help:

[Adding to "Open with" list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131583/adding-to-open-with-list)

A similar suggestion is offered here, with the additional suggestion of restarting Finder:

[How can I add a new application to the Open With menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu)

There is some detailed explanation of how that approach works in:

[How can I modify the list of Applications under 'Open With...'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with)

The above approach, suggested in other answers as well, does not quite answer your question because it requires adding specific file-type suffixes, not a "wild card". It also suffers from the fact that it will be overwritten at the next app update. To get around that, this suggestion is to create an Automator app that will appear in the list:

[How can I tell mac that program X can open file type Y?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443440/how-can-i-tell-mac-that-program-x-can-open-file-type-y)

Perhaps that approach will allow a "wild card" file type.

Answer (score 0):

The application [OpenInTermnial](https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal) allows you to define a set of applications to add to the contextual menu shown when right clicking on a file. BBEdit is one of the applications which can be added.

In the screenshot I've highlighted the items I've added:

[image]

So while it does not add it to the "Open With" menu, it is in the contextual menu. Which I would think would meet your need.

And just as a note to Tetsujin's comment, BBEdit can open JPEG files.