# How can I tell mac that program X can open file type Y?

Tags: macos, pdf, file, defaults

Firefox can open pdfs, and for some purposes, it's pdf viewer is advantageous. In particular, the print menu has some options not available elsewhere.

Unfortunately, it's not registered as a program that reads pdfs. I don't want it as the default pdf viewer, but I do want it on the list of programs that appear when I select "open-with".

How can I arrange that?

Comment: I’ll answer how things work and hope someone is more clever and knows how to invoke the PDF handler and teach us all a new trick. This might be easy without needing to modify the app for someone that knows the insides of how this specific helper works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could edit Firefox's `Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist` and add `<string>pdf</string>` e.g in the first `CFBundleTypeExtensions` array, but that would get ripped-off at the next Firefox update.

So instead you may prefer to build a new Automator Application that will open these files in Firefox.

So head to Automator, (Applications/Automator), "New" -> "Application".

On the left panel, search for "Open Finder Items", double click or drag&drop on the right panel.
In the "Open with" option, select Firefox.app.

[image: Screenshot of Automator setup as described]

Now is alredy time to export our App ("File" > "Export").

Then we go with the Finder to the location where we just exported the App, right-click, "Show Package Content" > "Contents" and we open *Info.plist* with our favorite editor (TextEdit should be fine).

Search for the string `<string>*</string>` below `CFBundleTypeExtensions` and replace it with `<string>pdf</string>`.
Save the document and go back to the Finder looking for a pdf file. Right-click, "Open with" > "Other..." and there select our App.
Firefox should open said pdf file and our App should appear in the menu:

[image: Screenshot of the Finder's context menu showing a new FirefoxPDF.app option]

Comment: Exceptional clever and skilled solution. Well done!

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought this didn't work, but actually I just needed to restart and check again.

Comment: Instead of making your Automator script an Application, you can make it a Quick Action, and it will show up directly on the contextual menu.

Answer (score 5):

*This doesn't actually answer the question, as it doesn't add it to the Open With list unfortunately. It only stays in the list if it's set as Default.

Frankly it's just quicker for a one-off to drop it straight on the Dock icon or right onto any open Firefox page.*

---

You can do this from Get Info… in the same way as selecting any already-registered app, except you select 'Other…', right at the bottom of the 'Open With:' list.
Once the file-picker dialog opens set 'Enable' at the bottom to 'All Apps' & choose Firefox.

You can then set 'Change All…' back in the Get Info pane.

[image]

Alternatively, for anyone on an OS old enough to still be able to run [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) [Mojave or earlier] you can do it in there. [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) doesn't seem to be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you don’t. The developer of the application [registers it (via code) to open file types using Apple SDK and API calls](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app). Then macOS let’s you choose a preferred app from all that support the types of a file.

Also, it’s [slightly more complicated than just PDF or pdf extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypereference/3548210-preferredfilenameextension) since each file has [many types that are mapped in code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttagclass) so the more specific type gets precedence in choosing an app over the more general types that will get consulted if the first choice doesn’t match.

Firefox is happy to pass PDF to other apps, but I’m not clever enough to find the embedded viewer and see if it can trick it to tell macOS it can open PDF outside the Firefox main app.

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer

In the mean time, what happens if you drag that PDF into Firefox windows or the icon?

Comment: Is the bit that tells macos what file types it can open a function of the compiled program itself, or its registration somewhere? If I wrote my own app, and wanted it to open an extension, how would I indicate that?

Comment: Good question @Clumsycat the technical term for a file type (which isn’t [just a preferred extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypereference/3548210-preferredfilenameextension), it’s more [nuanced](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttagclass)) is Uniform Type identifiers and here is how an app extends and declares its intents - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app

Answer (score 0):

The following Ask Different answer may help:

[Adding to "Open with" list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131583/adding-to-open-with-list)

A similar suggestion is offered here, with the additional suggestion of restarting Finder:

[How can I add a new application to the Open With menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu)

There is some detailed explanation of how that approach works in:

[How can I modify the list of Applications under 'Open With...'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/how-can-i-modify-the-list-of-applications-under-open-with)

This approach works, for instance, in specifying that BBEdit or MacVim can open `.webloc` files, which was your original question. Whether it works for your specific example of opening PDF files with a browser, I can't say. As @bmike points out, browsers can be more complicated.

As noted by @Kaiido above, the above approach suffers from the fact that it will be overwritten at the next app update, so you may prefer a non-`Info.plist` approach.